# Yii relation between myisam and innodb - column unknown

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've two tables, one myisam (boats), one innodb(landing_pages)

The relation between them works in SQL fine, but in yii I got the error-message
**bot_models_id is not defined, the relation used a wrong foreign key**

How can I deactivate this check, or do you know to to do it?

**My relation**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'landingPages'  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'LandingPages', 'boat_models_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

**Try to get the data**

```
$oCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$oCriteria->with = array(
    'landingPages'  => array('select' => 'url'),
);
$aBoats = Boats::model()->findAll($oCriteria);
```

print_r($aTmp);

thx!

Comment: in which model you defined your relation function?

Comment: its in boats.
When I'm using a column that uses a foreign key with an innodb table, then everything functions correct. Its only if I use a innodb to myisam connection

Comment: could you post the schema for the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii doesn't perform any foreign key check.
I suggest you to activate the sql log. You will immediatly find a wrong query. See this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/58/sql-logging-and-profiling-in-firebug-yii-1-1/
In my opinion the problem is the following:

```
public function relations()
{
  return array( 
      'landingPages'  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'LandingPages', 'boat_models_id',
      ),
  );
}
```

This mean that yii look for a field called boat_models_id in the table boats and this field appear as primary key in the table landingPages. I think this is not your case. I think that in your data model a boat **as many** landing pages and the field boat_models_id belong to the table landinbg_pages.
The right way to say this is:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'landingPages'  => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'LandingPages', 'boat_models_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

Take a look here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/it/database.arr